# Java Spring: Required parameter 'username' is not present

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, parameters

When I send the form, it will do action="userlogin" method="post".
This is my code:

```
package com.home_project.oop_project.controllers;

import java.sql.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class UserController {

int adminlogcheck = 0;
String usernameforclass = "";

//Some code
@GetMapping("userlogin")
public String userlog(Model model) {
    
    return "userLogin";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "userlogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String userlogin( @RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String pass,Model model) {
    try
    {
        System.out.println(username);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springproject","root","");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery("select * from users where username = '"+username+"' and password = '"+ pass+"' ;");
        if(rst.next()) {
            usernameforclass = rst.getString(2);
            return "redirect:/index";
            }
        else {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Invalid Username or Password");
            return "userLogin";
        }
        
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
    }
    return "userLogin";
    }
}
```

But it won't go to 'index' as I expected. When I check the issue by postman, it say: " "trace": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'username' for method parameter type String is not present\r\n\tat" and "message": "Required parameter 'username' is not present."
What should I do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Http request does not contain `userName` as you explicitly set the `username` to be needed.

```
  // you code -> @RequestParam("username") String username,
 // the http request(Missing username!)-> do action="userlogin" method="post". This is my code:
```

Answer (score -1):

```
RequestMapping(value = "userlogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String userlogin( @RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String pass,Model model) {
```

As you have defined the RequestParam, It needs to be as part of request URL , not a body.

http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-basics/api/login?username=abc

e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

If you intent to take it as part of body (which it must since password should not be in URL) then use following where loginInfo is DTO which stores username and password.

```
 RequestMapping(value = "userlogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userlogin( @RequestBody LoginInfo loginInfo) {
```